# Show all columns changing between two rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am required to use PostgresSql. I am given the following table called money as input

```
Cash | Adhoc | Collateral | Total
 ---------------------------------
 20  |   30  |    40      |   90
 32  |   12  |    40      |   84
 10  |   12  |    40      |   62
 13  |   20  |    50      |   83
```

As the name suggests, total is the sum of cash, adhoc and collateral values of that row.

I require the follwing output table

```
ChangeType  |  ChangeAmount
---------------------------
    Cash    |       12
    Adhoc   |      -18
    Cash    |      -22
    Cash    |       3
    Adhoc   |       8
 Collateral |       10
```

This is stage 1. In the next stage, a new column called clientId is to be added and these changes are to be shown for each specific client.
Say client1 is row 1, client 2 is row 2 and 3 and then client1 is row 4 again. Then the comparison table for client1 will be formed using row1 and row4.

The output table will be

```
  ChangeType  |  ChangeAmount |  ClientId
------------------------------------------
    Cash      |       7       |   client1
    Adhoc     |      -10      |   client1
 Collateral   |       10      |   client1
    Cash      |      -22      |   client2
```

I have been able to achieve what is chaging when "only one column" is changing between rows by using

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN ( (Cash - lag(Cash, 1)               
           OVER ( PARTITION BY clientId 
           ) ) != 0)  
     THEN CAST('Cash' AS Text)      
     WHEN ( (Adhoc - lag(Adhoc, 1)               
           OVER ( PARTITION BY clientId 
           ) ) != 0)  
     THEN CAST('Adhoc' AS Text)  
     WHEN ( (Collateral - lag(Collateral, 1)               
           OVER ( PARTITION BY clientId 
           ) ) != 0)  
     THEN CAST('Collateral' AS Text)
  END,
  Total - lag(Total,1)
  OVER ( PARTITION BY clientId )
     FROM money
```

I'm however lost how to show change for multiple columns changing in a row.

Comment: This is a special case of unpivoting. What you probably need to do is generate change records for every column of every row, then filter out the ones where the change is zero.

Comment: Thanks. Is unpivoting done at the query level or do I need to write soci c++ code?

Comment: I'd be very surprised if it wasn't practical at the SQL level. Provide usable, complete sample data as `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements (preferably as http://sqlfiddle.com) and I'll take a look, but I'm not feeling like making up the dummy data myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some cases procedural methods are much easier than pure SQL. I think this is the case. Try the function below:

```
create or replace function show_money_changes()
returns table (change_type text, change_amount integer)
language plpgsql
as $$
declare
    prev record;
    curr record;
    frst boolean = true;
begin
    for curr in select * from money --order by id
    loop
        if not frst then
            if curr.cash <> prev.cash then
                return query select 'cash'::text, curr.cash - prev.cash;
            end if;
            if curr.adhoc <> prev.adhoc then
                return query select 'adhoc'::text, curr.adhoc - prev.adhoc;
            end if;
            if curr.collateral <> prev.collateral then
                return query select 'collateral'::text, curr.collateral - prev.collateral;
            end if;
        end if;
        prev = curr;
        frst = false;
    end loop;
end $$;

select * from show_money_changes()
```

Note: you should have a column (say `id`) in `money` table to unambiguously order the rows.

---

Pure SQL solution (assuming that the table has id column with consecutive numbers):

```
select * from (
    select 
        unnest(array['cash', 'adhoc', 'collateral']) change_type,
        unnest(array[m2.cash- m1.cash, m2.adhoc- m1.adhoc, m2.collateral- m1.collateral]) change_value
    from money m1
    join money m2 on m1.id+ 1 = m2.id
    ) alias
where change_value <> 0
```

You'll have to change condition

```
on m1.id+ 1 = m2.id
```

(joining the *current* row with the *next* row) according to your actual table definition.

You can use `row_number()` for this purpose. Let's say `event_time` is a column to order by, then:

```
with money_with_row_numbers as (
    select *, row_number() over (order by event_time) rn
    from money)
select * from (
    select 
        unnest(array['cash', 'adhoc', 'collateral']) change_type,
        unnest(array[m2.cash- m1.cash, m2.adhoc- m1.adhoc, m2.collateral- m1.collateral]) change_value
    from money_with_row_numbers m1
    join money_with_row_numbers m2 on m1.rn+ 1 = m2.rn
    ) alias
where change_value <> 0
```

Comment: I have a timestamp column to order the rows. I didnt show it here as I felt(debatable though) that it didnt add much to the problem

Comment: @PranavKapoor - so add proper `order by` in the select.